# "Trailing" One-Hot Encode

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do something similar to One-Hot-Encoding but instead of the selected class being 1 and the rest zero, I want all the classes up to (and including the selected class) to be 1.  Say I have a training batch with labels (5 possible class labels; 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

```
y = np.array([0,2,1,3,4,1])
```

I can one-hot-encode with

```
def one_hot_encode(arr, num_classes):
    return np.eye(num_classes)[arr]
```

which gives

```
>>> one_hot_encode(y, 5)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

I liked to get

```
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by using a lower-triangular matrix instead of an identity matrix in your function definition:

```
def many_hot_encode(arr, num_classes):
    return np.tril(np.ones(num_classes))[arr]

many_hot_encode(y,5)
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
out = (y[:,None] >= np.arange(num_classes)).astype(float)
```

Sample run -

```
In [71]: y = np.array([0,2,1,3,4,1])

In [72]: num_classes = 5

In [73]: (y[:,None] >= np.arange(num_classes)).astype(float)
Out[73]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```